# Selecting the first 1 or 2 alpha characters from a postcode

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an example for a 3rd party who develop in Java (I use C#) but this isn't working as expected. I don't have any Java IDE on my machine so I'm using Ideone.com to test it.

The requirement is to take the first alpha part of the postcode (which could start with 1 or 2 alpha characters) to use in a separate lookup.

So given `MK34 8FD` I would expect `MK` and given `S4 8BF` I would expect `S`.

```
String source = "MK34 8FD";
String working = source.substring(0, 2);
String postcode = "";

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    String piece = working.substring(i, 1);
    if (piece.matches("[a-zA-Z]")) {
        postcode += piece;
    }
}
```

With the above code, `postcode` is always coming out as `M` and I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to [`substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) is the end index, not the length.

Thus

```
String piece = working.substring(i, 1);
```

needs to be changed to

```
String piece = working.substring(i, i + 1);
```

Comment: Aha thanks, I was operating under the assumption that it worked the same as C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
String source = "MK34 8FD";
String postCode = "";
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    char currentChar = source.charAt(i);
    if(Character.isLetter(currentChar))
        postCode += currentChar;
}
```